# How to draw the off-screen data in the framebuffer object to the QGLWidget?

Tags: c++, opengl, qtopengl

I use glGenFramebuffer, glBindFramebuffer and other related functions to create the Framebuffer Object(FBO) and I use the FBO to draw the off-screen data. Now my question is that I finish the mentioned steps inside QGLWidget and how can I draw the data in FBO back to QGLWidget? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you attached a color buffer to your framebuffer using

```
glFramebufferTexture2D( myfboID, GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_TEXTURE_2D, mytexID, 0);
```

Change the framebuffer to the widget by

```
glBindFrameBuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Simply render a QUAD textured with the previous texture. You can simply render a quad from [-1,-1] to [1,1] and with the above texture bound, and texture coordinates would be [0.0,0.0] - [1.0,1.0].